# how to pass parameters to an .onPress() in AS2?

Tags: flash, function, actionscript-2

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var something = "someValue";

some_btn.onPress = function (something) {
   someFunction(something);
}

function someFunction (argument) {
   trace(argument);
}
```

But it traces "undefined". What would be the correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPress()` doesn't take arguments.

You could make your own press function like this:

```
Object.prototype.myPress = function(str:String):Void
{
    // Delete old onPress.
    if(this["onPress"] != undefined) delete this.onPress;

    // Add new onPress.
    this.onPress = function():Void
    {
        someFunction(str);
    }
}
```

With your `someFunction()`:

```
function someFunction(str:String):Void
{
    trace(str);
}
```

And then implement like so:

```
some_btn.myPress("hello");
```

Comment: That totally does the trick, thanks a lot! (BTW, that's the second time you save my day)

Comment: @CCrawler And hopefully not the last :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var something = "someValue";

some_btn.onPress = function () {
   someFunction(something);
}

function someFunction (argument) {
   trace(argument);
}
```

Alternatively, this will also work:

```
var something = "someValue";

some_btn.onPress = function () {
   someFunction();
}

function someFunction () {
   trace(something);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you named your parameter equals the gloval variable name you've created:

```
var something = "someValue";
some_btn.onPress = function (something) { ...
```

This "creates a local variable" with the same name. Since local variables have preference and the onPress don't send any value, you got `undefined`.

To solve, remove the variable from the event handler as net.uk.sweet suggested:

```
some_btn.onPress = function () { ...
```